# need help for a simple javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation

This is my 1st post here after I've looked for a solution for my needs with no result
I'm not good at javascript and jquery and I know that my answer is there :)

Here is the code 
http://jsfiddle.net/6ncQR/51/

What I need is a simple function to rotate the `div` "box3" at different angles when hover over the `li` elements from the menu.

For example hovering 1st `li` child rotates `div` "box3" 45 degrees and the 2nd `li` child rotates "box3" 90 degrees and so on.

With pure css it is working only if the elements have the same parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make a example here.

http://jsbin.com/ayakol/1/edit

what I do is call the fuunction rotate with the proper name class .

```
function rotate(degrees){
    var t = document.getElementById("box2");
    t.className = degrees;

}
```

In HTML

```
<li onmouseover="rotate('box60');"><a href="#">sub2</a></li>
```

Comment: I`ve pasted your code and it seems that it`s not working for me.

Comment: sorry my mistake, i forgot to complete de css code. It is working now. Thx for your time